# How to keep the original order when use GROUP BY clause in SQLite3?

Tags: sqlite

In SQLite3, GROUP BY clause changes the order of extracted data. Is there any way to keep the original order?

Comment: Can you provide an example? what do you mean "changes the order"? `Select max(col1) col1max, col2, col3 from table group by col2, col3` should return col1max, col2, col3 in that order. Or do you mean the actual row order?

Comment: @cowbert
Suppose col1 has IDs and col2 has some numbers as counts. There can be the same IDs in different rows with different counts. I want to sum the counts together if the IDs are the same.
 `SELECT SUM(col2) FROM Table1 GROUP BY col1;`
Originally, col1 have some order. After running this query, the order will change.

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables are unordered; there is no "original order".

Queries never return any guaranteed order unless you actually use ORDER BY.